# How to assign 1 bit value?

Tags: c, gcc, variable-assignment, literals, bit-fields

Reading the pthread Library in structure the following is defined:

```
 struct ptw32_thread_t_
 {
      ....
      int implicit:1;
      ......
 };
```

I understand that it  occupy only 1 bit then how to give value to it as every value assigned with activate the Overflow Error Flags Compiling gives error:

```
 ptw32_thread_t *sp;
 sp = (ptw32_thread_t *) calloc (1, sizeof(ptw32_thread_t));
 sp->implicit = 1;

 error: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Werror=overflow]
```

Comment: Make it unsigned.  A 1-bit signed two's complement integer can only hold two values:  -1 and 0.  So 1 is an overflow condition.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks tom

Comment: @unwind The question you linked is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bad idea to have a 1-bit `int`, since it's a signed type. You can't represent `1` using 1 bit when using signed, you can only represent `0` and `-1`, which is a bit odd.

The solution is to make it `unsigned int implicit : 1`.